# App crashes when app I start the app and any pending notification is available

Tags: react-native, push-notification

when i send any notification to user when the app is not open and when i try to open the app it crashes on Samsung devices

https://pushy.me/docs/additional-platforms/react-native 
used this to send the push notification.

you can find whole code in the provided link.

Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) (a7y18lte), Android 9

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 


 at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.createMap (Arguments.java:163)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle (Arguments.java:287)
  at me.pushy.sdk.react.services.PushyNotificationService.getTaskConfig 

(PushyNotificationService.java:44)
  at com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService.onStartCommand (HeadlessJsTaskService.java:49)
  at me.pushy.sdk.react.receivers.PushReceiver.onReceive (PushReceiver.java:20)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3604)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1803)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7073)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.assertInitialized (SoLoader.java:781)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:505)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:484)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit (ReactBridge.java:30)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit> (NativeMap.java:19)
```

Comment: Did you perform all of the Android listings on the link?

Comment: yes...same as written on the page

Comment: Pushy founder here. Please make sure your `Pushy.setNotificationListener()` invocation is in your `App.js` **outside the Component declaration**, e.g. after the `import` statements.

Comment: Thank you for the response @EladNava .
But i did the same as written but still got this error on Samsung devices when app is closed (from recent apps) and receive any notification from backend(PHP) at that time app crashes .  can you please help me on this.

Comment: Hi @Saloni Parikh, please post your entire App.js code (or send it to us at support@pushy.me).

Comment: I already send queries to support@pushy.me. thank you for the response.